# Storing variadic unique_ptr pack into a tuple

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I am trying to write a constructor that takes a variadic pack of `unique_ptr`s as argument and store it in a tuple:

```cpp
template<class... E>
    class A
    {
        std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<E>...> a_;

    public:
        A(std::unique_ptr<E>&&... a)
           : a_(std::make_tuple(std::move(a)...)) {}
  
    };
```

but this fails to compile when I call the constructor with more than one argument --- e.g.

```cpp
A< double> obj(std::make_unique<double>(2.0), std::make_unique<double>(3.0));
```

fails to compile with an error in `tuple::test_method()`.

My questions are:

1. Is there anything inherently wrong in what I am trying to do?
2. Is it doable?

Thanks

Comment: Your constructor should be referencing `a` rather than `schemes` (undefined?), and your object should be `A<double, double>` rather than `A<double>`. But other than that, seems to work fine for me.

Comment: You're right. Using `schemes` was a typo (edited now). The problem was in the `<double>` vs `<double, double>` . I will accept it if you post it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: You meant `A<double, double>` since you're storing two `unique_ptr<double>`s.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like in this case the issue is just that your variable is type `A<double>` but you are passing two values, so you need to use `A<double, double>`.

```cpp
A<double, double> obj(std::make_unique<double>(2.0), std::make_unique<double>(3.0));
```

Alternatively, you can eliminate the need to state template parameters if you declare the variable with `auto`.

```cpp
auto obj = A(std::make_unique<double>(2.0), std::make_unique<double>(3.0));
```